# How to add spark to maven project iin Netbeans?

Tags: maven

I had added the following dependency [that I got from sparkjava.com of spark version 1.1.1](http://www.sparkjava.com/download.html)
under the  tag

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.sparkjava</groupId>
<artifactId>spark-core</artifactId>
<version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

but under project files it is not adding the classes or packages associated to it.

Answer (score 0):

Maven not copying the jars to your project files, add folowing plugin:

```
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
```

to your project and execute: mvn dependencies:build-classpath then you see where your jars are stored.

Maven copying your jars to the project only if you build a executable jars with the 'maven-assembly-plugin' .

Comment: showing error: Malformed POM , Unrecognised Tag <plugin> when tried to add the plugin code to pom file

Comment: a plugin is generally added in maven like:
<project>
<build>
<plugins>
<plugin>PLUGIN</plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
take a look at http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd